# Unable to learn weights of a Word2Vec model

Tags: machine-learning, python, tensorflow, word2vec, implementation

I was going to implement a word embedding model - namely Word2Vec - by following [this TensorFlow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/representation/word2vec) and adapting the code a little bit. Unfortunately, though, my model won't learn anything. I've used TensorBoard to keep track of the value of the loss function *and* to observe how the network's weights evolve over time. Here's what I found:

1. The value of the loss function keeps fluctuating up and down
2. The network's weights stay constant during the training process

I honestly can't understand why this is happening. I've tried setting "trainable=True" explicitly when creating variables, but that didn't help either.
Here's the code that I'm using right now:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

vocabulary_size = 13046
embedding_size = 256
num_noise = 1
learning_rate = 1e-3
batch_size = 1024
epochs = 10

def make_hparam_string(embedding_size, num_noise, learning_rate, batch_size, epochs):
    return f'es={embedding_size}_nn={num_noise}_lr={learning_rate}_bs={batch_size}_e={epochs}'

# These are the hidden layer weights
embeddings = tf.get_variable(name='embeddings', initializer=tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0), trainable=True)

# 'nce' stands for 'Noise-contrastive estimation' and represents a particular loss function.
# Check https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/representation/word2vec for more details.
# 'nce_weights' and 'nce_biases' are simply the output weights and biases.
# NOTE: for some reason, even though output weights will have shape (embedding_size, vocabulary_size),
#       we have to initialize them with the shape (vocabulary_size, embedding_size)
nce_weights = tf.get_variable(name='output_weights',
                              initializer=tf.truncated_normal([vocabulary_size, embedding_size], stddev=1.0 / np.sqrt(embedding_size)), 
                              trainable=True)
nce_biases = tf.get_variable(name='output_biases', initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.1), shape=[vocabulary_size], trainable=True)

# Placeholders for inputs
train_inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None])    # [batch_size]
train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, 1]) # [batch_size, 1]

# This allows us to quickly retrieve the corresponding word embeddings for each word in 'train_inputs'
matched_embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_inputs)

# Compute the NCE loss, using a sample of the negative labels each time.
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.nce_loss(weights=nce_weights,
                                     biases=nce_biases,
                                     labels=train_labels,
                                     inputs=matched_embeddings,
                                     num_sampled=num_noise,
                                     num_classes=vocabulary_size))

# Use the SGD optimizer to minimize the loss function
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(loss)

# Add some summaries for TensorBoard
loss_summary = tf.summary.scalar('nce_loss', loss)
input_embeddings_summary = tf.summary.histogram('input_embeddings', embeddings)
output_embeddings_summary = tf.summary.histogram('output_embeddings', nce_weights)

################################################################################

# Load data
target_words = np.genfromtxt('target_words.txt', dtype=int, delimiter='\n').reshape((-1, 1))
context_words = np.genfromtxt('context_words.txt', dtype=int, delimiter='\n').reshape((-1, 1))

# Convert to tensors
target_words_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(target_words)
context_words_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(context_words)

# Create a tf.data.Dataset object representing our dataset
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((target_words_tensor, context_words_tensor))
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=target_words.shape[0])
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)

# Create an iterator to iterate over the dataset
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
next_batch = iterator.get_next()

# Train the model
with tf.Session() as session:

    # Initialize variables
    session.run( tf.global_variables_initializer() )

    merged_summary = tf.summary.merge_all()

    # File writer for TensorBoard
    hparam_string = make_hparam_string(embedding_size, num_noise, learning_rate, batch_size, epochs)
    loss_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(f'./tensorboard/{hparam_string}')

    global_step = 0
    for epoch in range(epochs):

        session.run(iterator.initializer)
        while True:
            try:
                inputs, labels = session.run(next_batch)

                feed_dict = {train_inputs: inputs[:, 0], train_labels: labels}
                _, cur_loss, all_summaries = session.run([optimizer, loss, merged_summary], feed_dict=feed_dict)

                # Write sumaries to disk
                loss_writer.add_summary(all_summaries, global_step=global_step)
                global_step += 1

                print(f'Current loss: {cur_loss}')

            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                print(f'Finished epoch {epoch}.')
                break
```

Answer (score -1):

From your code it appears you are running for 10 epochs. It is highly improbable that your model will make significant progress in so few epochs. You might start to see learning after 1000 epochs, but large scale implementations of word2vec often require millions of epochs and take months to train to an acceptable level.